# Automatic Stretch shown in Expression and Visual Studio doesn't happen in Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

here is the xaml for it  when i try to scroll using the scroll viewer the second items control doesn't stretch to accomodate all of the data.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"  
    x:Class="CheeroJusa.Views.RecipeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ../SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Width="480" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding SelectedRecipe.Name}" Margin="0,-7,-4,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Height="44" />
            <Canvas x:Name="grid1" Height="2000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,0">
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textBlock1" Text="Prep Time" Width="93" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="1" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" x:Name="textBlock2" Text="Cook Time" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Canvas.Left="158" Canvas.Top="1" Width="113" />
                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="textBlock3" Text="Serves" Width="58" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Canvas.Left="353" Canvas.Top="1" />
                <TextBlock Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtPrep" Text="{Binding SelectedRecipe.PrepTime}" Width="90" TextAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="28" />
                <TextBlock Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtCook" Text="{Binding SelectedRecipe.CookTime}" Width="90" TextAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="162" Canvas.Top="29" />
                <TextBlock Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtServe" Text="{Binding SelectedRecipe.Serves}" Width="58" TextAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="353" Canvas.Top="28" />
                <Grid x:Name="gridScrollView" Height="Auto" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="59" Width="481">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock5" Text="Ingredients" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" FontSize="29.333" Height="59" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
                            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </TextBlock.Foreground></TextBlock>
                        <ItemsControl  x:Name="ingList" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRecipe.ingredients}" Background="Transparent" Margin="9,59,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid x:Name="grid5" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" Margin="12,0,12,11" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" />
                                        <!--<toolkit:Separator BorderThickness="1" Width="410" Margin="20,0,19,4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                            <toolkit:Separator.BorderBrush>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </toolkit:Separator.BorderBrush>
                                        </toolkit:Separator>-->
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--<toolkit:Separator Height="12" Margin="0,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" />-->
                    <Grid d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Text="Instructions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="29.333" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment">
                            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </TextBlock.Foreground></TextBlock>
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="lstSteps" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRecipe.steps}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="5,55,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Height="Auto">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                                            
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StepOrder}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Width="23" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" Margin="35,0,19,0" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <!--<toolkit:Separator Margin="0,221,0,0" Height="12" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3">
                        <toolkit:Separator.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </toolkit:Separator.BorderBrush>
                    </toolkit:Separator>-->


                </Grid>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>    
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Put in latest code 12/31/2010

the height 2000 for the canvas is just there to test stuff doing it "auto" reduces is to be much much shorter.

Comment: I've put your xaml in a page and see the same thing in the emulator as I do in the Visual Studio designer. I'm just not sure what I should be looking for or how to recreate it. Can you provide examples (mock-ups are fine) of what you're trying to do and what you're getting.

Comment: what happens is that when I run this page and try to scroll the page up the scroll viewer doesn't go beyoned the top edge of page also. the second itemsControl doesn't stretch to accommodate all the items it has.

Comment: Ok so I got it working by changing layoutroot to a scrollview instead of a grid and changing bottom scrollview into a grid. but how should I now make some fixed area that doesn't scroll?

Comment: Then again it doesn't work :(.. with the first listbox stretching much longer the second is limited by some unknown amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've finally fixed it by setting the vertical alignment to top for second itemscontrol and it seems tobe stretching fine.. though can't really answer why :(..

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the contents of your ScroillViewer in a single container. ie StackPanel or another Grid.

Comment: Isn't StackPanel non stretchable? if you look at xaml all of the contents of ScrollViewer are in "gridScrollView"